# Compare dates in different years knex javascript

Tags: javascript, date, compare, momentjs, knex.js

I am using knex to get a list of clients with their birth dates on mysql.
I want to get only clients that are having birthday on the next month.
I think the best way is to compare dates ignoring the year, but I can't find anywhere how to do that.
I don't know if there is a better ways to get the birthdate..

```
let date1 = moment(new Date(), "DD/MM");
let date2 = moment(new Date(), "DD/MM").add(1, "M");

function getClients(req, res){
     app.db('.clients')
         .select(clients.*)
         .modify(function (queryBuilder) {
                queryBuilder
                .format('clients.birth', 'DD-MM') 
                .where('clients.birth', '>=', date1).andWhere('clients.birth', '<=', date2)
            })
        .then(clients => res.json(clients))
}
```

Comment: You could probably use SQL to first limit the result set. For example `EXTRACT` function allows you to only take one part of a datetime. You could probably go even further and add a where clause to SQL and limit the data based on the results of `EXTRACT` and so return only those entities from db that have a birthday coming in next month.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work using the .whereRaw with the EXTRACT MONTH and EXTRACT DAY from the sql.

```
let today = moment(new Date(), "DD/MM/YYYY");
let next_month = moment(today).add(1, "M");
let present_month = moment(today).format("MM");
today = moment(today).format("DD")
next_month = moment(next_month).format("MM"); 

function getClients(req, res){
     app.db('.clients')
         .select(clients.*)
         .where(function (qb) {
                qb
                this.whereRaw(`EXTRACT(MONTH FROM clients.birth) = ?`, [present_month])
                    .andWhereRaw(`EXTRACT(DAY FROM clients.birth) > ?`, [today])
            })
         .orWhere(function (qb) {
                qb
                this.whereRaw(`EXTRACT(MONTH FROM clients.birth) = ?`, [next_month])
                    .andWhereRaw(`EXTRACT(DAY FROM clients.birth) < ?`, [today])
            })
        .then(clients => res.json(clients))
}
```

That way I get the clients who are having a birthday within 1 month from the request date.

Comment: Nice! Remember to accept your own answer as the solution after 24 hours.